# Contents of dashboard are not displayed when I deploy on heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have a dashboard that looks like this. [image: Dashboard when executed locally]

I used the same code to deploy it on heroku. But now all the subsequent divisions are not displayed. [image: Dashboard on heroku]

Is such an error normal ? What could be wrong with my application ? Any suggestions would be really helpful.

The server errors are included below :

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.

2020-07-06T09:43:04.129612+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.119.250 - - [06/Jul/2020:09:43:04 +0000] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-07-06T09:43:04.130124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/_dash-update-component" host=villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com request_id=19c8d83c-98fe-45de-b383-05faa6063975 fwd="103.125.155.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=470 protocol=https
```

```
2020-07-06T09:43:04.123913+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
2020-07-06T09:43:04.123931+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/_dash-update-component" host=villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com request_id=134a6cd3-834c-47b9-a8e1-7aaef08af483 fwd="103.125.155.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=470 protocol=https
2020-07-06T09:43:04.124736+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.238.92 - - [06/Jul/2020:09:43:04 +0000] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
```

```
2020-07-06T09:43:04.122205+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
2020-07-06T09:43:04.122553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/_dash-update-component" host=villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com request_id=e97ce186-b12c-425d-8ebf-a4266624f241 fwd="103.125.155.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=470 protocol=https
2020-07-06T09:43:04.122945+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.29.116.130 - - [06/Jul/2020:09:43:04 +0000] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
```

```
2020-07-06T09:43:03.742186+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.5.185.29 - - [06/Jul/2020:09:43:03 +0000] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-07-06T09:43:03.742413+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/_dash-update-component" host=villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com request_id=78a47588-822c-45e7-9689-83e65ceaad54 fwd="103.125.155.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=470 protocol=https
2020-07-06T09:43:03.742473+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.171.23.45 - - [06/Jul/2020:09:43:03 +0000] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-07-06T09:43:03.746077+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/_dash-update-component" host=villages-india-dashboard.herokuapp.com request_id=78a48ccd-f8c4-458a-b091-20507030c457 fwd="103.125.155.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=500 bytes=470 protocol=https
```

Comment: Check your server logs

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I viewed my logs and there seems to be some error. But I can't understand what it is, I'll include it in the question.

Comment: Include the error in the question

Comment: Do `pip install xlrd` in the server

Comment: I installed it and uploaded again, worked now. Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: I'll write this as an answer so that other people who land up at the same problem can go through a consolidated answer rather than the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is not working, then

1. Check your server logs and find if any exception is thrown
2. In your case, there's a library that was missing i.e `xlrd`
3. Run `pip install xlrd`
4. Restart the app

If you are running a web application, then better you use `virtualenv` or `conda` environment and a `requirements.txt` that contains all the dependencies.

Before running the app, do `pip install -r requirements.txt` so that all the requirements are installed correctly